# Error with less than character when use Nokogiri parse html

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I use `Nokogiri` to parse html [link](https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=21.01127405231557,105.86252250209158&intent=browse&radius=50&oauth_token=VJZUMY5KPVGFNSNQTKZEG5BXTNZAZA51NPQM20UBXVB5OHMO&v=20140414) in ruby. There is a "<3" character in it's content. So, Nokogiri see it as a open tag and i can't get all it's content. How can i solve it? Thank you!

Comment: Interesting content `"<3"`.. hehehe

Comment: @ArupRakshit Can you help me with this ?

Comment: I am far away from my laptop where Ruby is installed. I can answer now only theoretical questions. You would get answer very soon from someone else. Don't worry. :-)

Comment: The link is to a JSON API. There is no HTML. Instead of Nokogiri, you'll need a JSON parser. Or an API client like HTTParty.

Comment: @MarkThomas Can you example for me with that link use JSON.parse ? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to use HTTParty, simply create a class with access methods for each endpoint, for example `search`.

```
require 'httparty'

class FourSquare
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'api.foursquare.com/v2'

  def initialize
    @token = "VJZUMY5KPVGFNSNQTKZEG5BXTNZAZA51NPQM20UBXVB5OHMO"
  end

  def search(what=:venues, radius=50, lat_long="21.01127405231557,105.86252250209158")
    options = {ll:lat_long, intent:"browse", radius:radius, oauth_token:@token, v:"20140414"}
    self.class.get("/#{what}/search", query: options)
  end
end
```

use it like this:

```ruby
fs = FourSquare.new
result = fs.search #optional parameters here
```

Now `result` has the response, already parsed into a Ruby hash:

```
{"meta"=>{"code"=>200},
 "notifications"=>[{"type"=>"notificationTray", "item"=>{"unreadCount"=>0}}],
 "response"=>
  {"venues"=>
    [{"id"=>"512ae67ee4b0861e65cc6d1d",
      "name"=>"tại gia",
      "contact"=>{},
      "location"=>
       {"lat"=>21.01130249367748,
        "lng"=>105.86250172574675,
        "distance"=>3,
        "cc"=>"VN",
        "country"=>"Vietnam"},
      "categories"=>[],
      "verified"=>false,
      "stats"=>{"checkinsCount"=>2, "usersCount"=>2, "tipCount"=>0},
      "specials"=>{"count"=>0, "items"=>[]},
      "hereNow"=>{"count"=>0, "summary"=>"0 people here", "groups"=>[]},
      "referralId"=>"v-1397697176"},
     {"id"=>"4f191ed9e4b08b384dcc274c",
      "name"=>"Chợ Đuổi Nguyễn Cao",
      "contact"=>{},
      "location"=>
       {"address"=>"Nguyễn Cao",
        "crossStreet"=>"Yersin",
        "lat"=>21.01157363534264,
        "lng"=>105.86230101953188,
        "distance"=>40,
        "cc"=>"VN",
        "city"=>"Hà Nội",
        "state"=>"Thành Phố Hà Nội",
        "country"=>"Việt Nam"},
      "categories"=>
       [{"id"=>"50be8ee891d4fa8dcc7199a7",
         "name"=>"Market",
         "pluralName"=>"Markets",
         "shortName"=>"Market",
         "icon"=>
          {"prefix"=>"https://ss1.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/shops/default_",
           "suffix"=>".png"},
         "primary"=>true}],
      "verified"=>false,
      "stats"=>{"checkinsCount"=>24, "usersCount"=>9, "tipCount"=>0},
      "specials"=>{"count"=>0, "items"=>[]},
      "hereNow"=>{"count"=>0, "summary"=>"0 people here", "groups"=>[]},
      "referralId"=>"v-1397697176"},
     {"id"=>"4f310be1e4b0f99d87e0ebff",
      "name"=>"Ngõ 158 Phường Bạch Đằng",
      "contact"=>{},
      "location"=>
       {"isFuzzed"=>true,
        "lat"=>21.012500145519407,
        "lng"=>105.85838729146847,
        "distance"=>450,
        "cc"=>"VN",
        "city"=>"Hà Nội",
        "state"=>"Thành Phố Hà Nội",
        "country"=>"Việt Nam"},
      "categories"=>
       [{"id"=>"4bf58dd8d48988d103941735",
         "name"=>"Home (private)",
         "pluralName"=>"Homes (private)",
         "shortName"=>"Home",
         "icon"=>
          {"prefix"=>"https://ss1.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/building/home_",
           "suffix"=>".png"},
         "primary"=>true}],
      "verified"=>false,
      "stats"=>{"checkinsCount"=>19, "usersCount"=>2, "tipCount"=>0},
      "specials"=>{"count"=>0, "items"=>[]},
      "hereNow"=>{"count"=>0, "summary"=>"0 people here", "groups"=>[]},
      "referralId"=>"v-1397697176"},
     {"id"=>"505b08bde4b016e61b081acc",
      "name"=>"trước gương - ở nhà <3",
      "contact"=>{},
      "location"=>
       {"lat"=>21.0113,
        "lng"=>105.8625,
        "distance"=>3,
        "cc"=>"VN",
        "country"=>"Vietnam"},
      "categories"=>[],
      "verified"=>false,
      "stats"=>{"checkinsCount"=>2, "usersCount"=>1, "tipCount"=>0},
      "specials"=>{"count"=>0, "items"=>[]},
      "hereNow"=>{"count"=>0, "summary"=>"0 people here", "groups"=>[]},
      "referralId"=>"v-1397697176"},
     {"id"=>"4e1878a71f6eb955987a0ef4",
      "name"=>"CMIV's house",
      "contact"=>{},
      "location"=>
       {"isFuzzed"=>true,
        "lat"=>21.012500145519407,
        "lng"=>105.85838729146847,
        "distance"=>450,
        "cc"=>"VN",
        "city"=>"Hà Nội",
        "state"=>"Thành Phố Hà Nội",
        "country"=>"Việt Nam"},
      "categories"=>
       [{"id"=>"4bf58dd8d48988d103941735",
         "name"=>"Home (private)",
         "pluralName"=>"Homes (private)",
         "shortName"=>"Home",
         "icon"=>
          {"prefix"=>"https://ss1.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/building/home_",
           "suffix"=>".png"},
         "primary"=>true}],
      "verified"=>false,
      "stats"=>{"checkinsCount"=>1, "usersCount"=>1, "tipCount"=>0},
      "specials"=>{"count"=>0, "items"=>[]},
      "hereNow"=>{"count"=>0, "summary"=>"0 people here", "groups"=>[]},
      "referralId"=>"v-1397697176"},
     {"id"=>"4f58d391e4b0cd6f8d2f5c44",
      "name"=>"Cty TNHH PR&Pr Việt Nam",
      "contact"=>{},
      "location"=>
       {"isFuzzed"=>true,
        "lat"=>21.012500145519407,
        "lng"=>105.85838729146847,
        "distance"=>450,
        "cc"=>"VN",
        "city"=>"Cầu Giấy",
        "state"=>"Thành Phố Hà Nội",
        "country"=>"Việt Nam"},
      "categories"=>
       [{"id"=>"4bf58dd8d48988d103941735",
         "name"=>"Home (private)",
         "pluralName"=>"Homes (private)",
         "shortName"=>"Home",
         "icon"=>
          {"prefix"=>"https://ss1.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/building/home_",
           "suffix"=>".png"},
         "primary"=>true}],
      "verified"=>false,
      "stats"=>{"checkinsCount"=>0, "usersCount"=>0, "tipCount"=>0},
      "specials"=>{"count"=>0, "items"=>[]},
      "hereNow"=>{"count"=>0, "summary"=>"0 people here", "groups"=>[]},
      "referralId"=>"v-1397697176"}]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The content of the page is not html, but a json.

Use [`JSON.parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) to parse it.

```
obj = JSON.parse(content)
```

Comment: But I have to parse html to get content. That content now is json

Comment: @DoThanhTung, As in the answer, there's no html, but only json.

Comment: Sorry for my English skill, maybe, i don't understand your answer. But, i think to have only json, not html,i have to get html's content.The result now is json, before using Nokogiri, it's not only json, but json in html. Can you explain for me? Thank you!